# How can i check if user changed post value?

Tags: php, forms, post

I have a form for users to give reputations to people.

I'm trying to check if user changed select value to cheat by giving more points

Here is my system:
There is a select box where users can choose how many reputation to give to the user, I'm using the following code to check if user changed the values by inspecting the element:

```
// Validate post
if(trim($_POST["reputationToGive"]) === 1){
    $added = 1;
} elseif(trim($_POST["reputationToGive"]) === 2){
    $added = 2;
} elseif(trim($_POST["reputationToGive"]) === 3){
    $added = 3;
} else {
    // fallback event
}
```

Code I'm using for select box:

```
<option value='1'>Give 1 reputation</option>
```

But somehow, it always triggers the fallback event.
Looking for corrections, have a great day!

Comment: You're checking for identity (`===`) of the values, so instead of `trim()` you should rather use `intval()`. If that shouldn't work you know that people are very generous. ;-)

Comment: @digijay neither using intval(trim($_POST["role"])) === 3 nor using intval($_POST["role"]) === 3 worked for me

Comment: `$_POST["role"]`?? I thought you would check `$_POST["reputationToGive"]`. What does role contain then?

Comment: @digijay i'm checking for role but posted it as reputationToGive to make it clearer for you to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the === gives you the problem.

I don't know how you wrote the selectbox. But my geuss is that you get strings back and compare it to integers. Also trim will convert it to string.

I also suggest using a switch for this.

```
$value = (int) trim($_POST["reputationToGive"]);
$added = 0;
switch ( $value ) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        $added = $value;
        break;

    default:
        // fallback event
        break;
}
```

If you want to be sure the answer is not changed in the post. You could use totally different values in the form that you will translate to the right value in the script.

```
$value = trim($_POST["reputationToGive"]);
$added = 0;
switch ( $value ) {
    case 'AD3ZY':
        $added = 1;
        break;
    case 'B&7X1':
        $added = 2;
        break;
    case 'Px!29':
        $added = 3;
        break;

    default:
        // fallback event
        break;
}
```

Comment: I updated my code, you can now see how i wrote the selectbox.

Comment: If you also want to check if the post values are changed, you could put something totally different in the values, that you translate to a value in this script.

Comment: Your last suggestion solved my thing! Thank you very much. Post it as an answer so i can mark it as solution.